# How to ensure attribute doesnt exist if None when using pydantic basemodel

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

If one attribute is None, then that attribute should not even exist. So I have code written as follows:

Using default OOPs concepts:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, c, t=None):
        self.c = c
        if t:
            self.t = t

c1 = C(c=1, t=2)
print(c1.t) #prints 2
c1 = C(c=1)
print(c1.t) #throws error
```

My intention is to use Pydantic instead. I have come up with the following:

```
class C(BaseModel):
    c: int
    def __init__(self, **data):
        if data.get("t"):
            data["t"] = data.get("t")
        super().__init__(**data)


c1 = C(c=1, t=2)
print(c1.t) #throws error
c1 = C(c=1)
print(c1.t) #throws error
```

I have the following:

```
class C(BaseModel):
    c: int
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='allow')
```

But this would allow additional arguments. I only want to restrict to one more with a clearly defined name

Comment: To make `c1 = C(c=1, t=2)  print(c1.t)` in your second example work you should add `model_config = ConfigDict(extra='allow')` to your model. By default pydantic models ignore all extra fields

Comment: @YuriiMotov But that would mean any number of extra fields, I wish to avoid that and to restrict to one addtional and clearly defined variable

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `model_config = ConfigDict(extra='allow')` to your model to allow using extra fields.

And in `__init__` method you should remove `t` key if it exists in the `data` dict and is equal to `None`. And remove all extra fields except `t` as well.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class C(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='allow')
    c: int
    def __init__(self, **data):
        for k in dict(data).keys():
            if k == "t":
                if data.get("t") is None:
                    data.pop("t")
            elif k not in self.__class__.model_fields.keys():
                data.pop(k)

        super().__init__(**data)


c1 = C(c=1, t=2)
print(c1.t) # prints 2


c1 = C(c=1)
try:
    print(c1.t) # throws error
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)


c1 = C(c=1, t=None)
try:
    print(c1.t) # throws error
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)


c1 = C(c=1, tt=2)
try:
    print(c1.tt) # throws error
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
```